# How can I set a different backgroundImage in <div> element in a .map() function?

Tags: css, styled-components, react-tsx

I want to give each `CategoryCard` div a different `background-image`.

How can I solve this problems with styled components? I use React and Typescript.

```
{this.MainChannels.map(item => {
  return (
    <CategoryCard key={item._id} onClick={() => this.handleChannel(item.name)}>
      {item.name}
    </CategoryCard>)
})}
```

the URL's of the images are locally it means my pictures are stored on my computer

Comment: We probably need a little more info to answer this question (where do the image URLs come from?), but in general have you tried just using a `style` attribute on your `CategoryCard`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with importing of each image and inline styling of the CategoryCard.

then i pushed the imports in an array. And every item in the .map() function gets the own background through the array.

[image: show solution]